# Different assembly syntaxes for same cpu?

Tags: linux, assembly, syntax, compiler-construction, nasm

I've decided to learn assembler through online tutorials.

I've come across this one that uses the NASM compiler, which most other tutorials seem to as well:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/index.htm

I've also come across this youtube series "Assembly primer for hackers"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0g-twyhmQ4&list=PLue5IPmkmZ-P1pDbF3vSQtuNquX0SZHpB
This one uses what the guy describes as the 'generic linux compiler' (owtte).
The commands for compiling go something like this:

`as -o file.o file.s`

Where file.s is the assembly source code.  Followed by:

```
ld -o file file.o
```

Where file is then the executable.

Each of the tutorials uses a different syntax (e.g. a register in the latter tutorial is always preceded by %. NB. There do appear to be less superficial differences in the syntax than this as well).  Are these syntaxes decided by the individual compiler?

I was also initially confused when I tried to compile code from the NASM tutorial with the latter method. I was always under the impression that the instruction set had to depend on the CPU and it therefore shouldn't matter which compiler I use.  I've just concluded that it's merely differences in syntax but is that correct?

I'm running a Linux computer, by the way, on kernel 4.1.6.

My main question is really which syntax do I use?  Is it just a matter of choice?  Is one more widely used than the other?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, the syntaxes are defined by the assemblers, although for x86 the actual instruction mnemonics come in two flavors, intel and at&t. The directives and other syntax elements may vary more. Also note that `as` and most GNU tools can be switched to intel mode.

Comment: Ok, well given that I'm on an intel CPU, I guess I should use intel instructions? (i.e. Do I have a choice?).  Also if I switched 'as' into intel mode would it then be able to compile the stuff from the NASM tutorial?

Comment: Both syntaxes produce output that can run on intel or compatible cpus. Unfortunately `as` in intel mode is still not the same as `nasm`, so you won't be able to compile `nasm` code unchanged.

Comment: ok thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each of the tutorials uses a different syntax (e.g. a register in the
>   latter tutorial is always preceded by %. NB. There do appear to be
>   less superficial differences in the syntax than this as well). Are
>   these syntaxes decided by the individual compiler?

Yes, different assemblers (= assembly language compilers) might use different assembler language syntax although they provide code for the same processor and platform.

> My main question is really which syntax do I use? Is it just a matter
>   of choice? Is one more widely used than the other?

One assembler, like NASM, might go for a wide range of processors and platforms, in this case you would benefit from learning its syntax when you need to work with several processors or platforms.

In other cases it might be better to stick with the assembler of some prominent vendor, because it is widely used and you can find more example code on the net for it which might help you with your development.

Last not least you might simply prefer a particular assembler because you like its features or syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If your'e on a Windows system, Microsoft's MASM (ML.EXE or ML64.exe for 64 bit) syntax is virtually the same as Intel's syntax. MASM (ML.EXE and ML64.EXE) is included with the free Visual Studio express editions, although you usually have to create a custom build step to invoke the assembler in a VS project. VS express includes a good source level debugger.

If you're on a Linux type system, then you'll probably use AT&T syntax, which I assume ended up that way since it was a conversion of some generic assembler. I don't know which assembler(s) to recommend for Linux.